# JS comparing strings with line breaks

Tags: javascript, string, backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to compare two equal strings: a `textarea` value (or `textContent`, or `innerHTML`) and a string stored as an attribute in Backbone model, e.g. `"A string↵with line break"`. 
And this comparing always returns `false`.
Comparing length of these strings reveals the difference (the stored one is one symbol longer).
The question is how to prepare the first string (extracted from `textarea`) to make it completely equal to the second one (stored in model).

P.S. They are both `typeof === 'string'`.

P.P.S.
The main problem is how to make Backbone see the equality while setting an attribute:

`this.model.set({ attr: textareaValue })`.

Backbone uses Underscore's method which simply compares two strings in this case:

`return '' + a === '' + b;`

I've applied `encodeURIComponent` on both strings: the result is `Some%0Atext` vs `Some%0D%0Atext`. So the second one has `\r` character (it's rendered by Handlebars). Should I insert this character before each `\n`?

P.P.P.S. Yes, this did the trick: `textarea.value.replace(/\n/gm, '\r\n');`

Comment: Replace on `/\r?\n/g` so you don't end up with `\r\r\n` if the string does have the `\r`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in `\r` character: textarea value rendered by Handlebars was `Some\ntext` while string stored in model was  `Some\r\ntext`). 
And this did the trick: `textarea.value.replace(/\n/gm, '\r\n');`

Comment: Instead of replacing the line ends myself, I find it useful to use https://github.com/ryanve/eol

Answer (score 5):

My first thought is to remove all non alpha characters from both strings and compare them afterward.

```
str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "");
```

Comment: Yes, it works! But the problem is how to make Backbone see this equality while setting an attribute: ```this.model.set({ attr: textareaValue })```. It uses Underscore's method which simply compares two strings in this case: ```return '' + a === '' + b;```

Comment: Which string has the line break?

Comment: I've applied encodeURIComponent on both strings: the result is ```Some%0Atext vs Some%0D%0Atext```. So you see that the second one has /r character (it's rendered by Handlebars).

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just run the replace on them both before comparing, but I don't know backbone. Sorry.

Comment: Simply because the comparison is made by Backbone internally... Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you can apply the encode before backbone performs the comparison then why can't you perform the replace as well? :)